# Django-like button is not updating the likes

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

I am nearing completion of the Tango with Django tutorial, I'm near homestretch, in the process of making a 'like' button:

http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book17/chapters/ajax.html#add-a-like-button
What is supposed to happen is:

> when the button is clicked an AJAX request is made, given our url
>   mapping, this invokes the like_category view which updates the
>   category and returns the new number of likes. When the AJAX request
>   receives the response it updates parts of the page, i.e. the text and
>   the button. The #likes button is hidden.

My button is there, can be clicked, but does not hide after being clicked, nor does it actual increment the number of likes, and I'm not sure why, I successfully created buttons in the previous introductory chapter.

These are the relevant code snippets (but let me know if there is something that I missed which could be helpful:

**views.py**

```
@login_required

def like_category(request):

    cat_id = None
    if request.method == 'GET':
        cat_id = request.GET['post_id']

    likes = 0
    if cat_id:
        cat = Post.objects.get(id=int(cat_id))
        if cat:
            likes = cat.likes + 1
            cat.likes =  likes
            cat.save()

    return HttpResponse(likes)
```

---

**rango-ajax.js**

```
    $('#likes').click(function(){
        var catid;
        catid = $(this).attr("data-catid");
        $.get('/rango/like_category/', {category_id: catid}, function(data){
                   $('#like_count').html(data);
                   $('#likes').hide();
        });
    });
```

---

**about.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block body_block %}
<p>

<strong id="like_count">{{ post.likes }}</strong> people like this category

{% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <button id="likes" data-catid="{{post.id}}" class="btn btn-primary" type="button">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span>
        Like
        </button>
{% endif %}
</p>

<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/rango-ajax.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock %}
{% endblock %}
```

---

**models.py**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    post = models.TextField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
    def __str__(self):
        return self.post
```

---

This is what my console shows me when I click on the like button:

```
Not Found: /assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js [19/Apr/2017 06:55:29] "GET /assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js HTTP/1.1" 404 5180 [19/Apr/2017 06:55:29] "GET /static/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff HTTP/1.1" 404 1730 [19/Apr/2017 06:55:29] "GET /static/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf HTTP/1.1" 404 1727
```

Comment: It could help if you type in the ajax url in your browser manually. Then you can see the error trace log if the problem is related to your view, and copy that information in your question. Also: please add your urls.py

Comment: @dentemm Thanks for the response. I have added urls.py to the question

Comment: Okay, there are several things wrong with your code. First of all, your url does not accept any variables. Best read [URL Dispatcher](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/urls/) on the official django docs first. Secondly, since your are going to update your database you should use a POST request instead of a GET request. I think it would help if you try the django tutorial first to improve your understanding.